# Does :include work on ActiveRecord instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

All the examples of :include for eager loading are for class-level querying. I tried it on my model instance and it still issued a bunch of queries - does it work on instance methods?

```
 #in controller
 @emails = person.sent_emails(:include => [:recipient])

 #in view
 render @emails

 # _email.html.erb partial
 <h1><%= email.recipient.name %></h1>
 <p>
 <%= email.content %>
 </p>

 #still issues a select * for emails, N+1 for recipients :/
```

Comment: What is inside the partial `_email`?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: The `email.recipient` call should run `select * from users` if the recipient is not eager loaded. Are you sure you are seeing `select * from emails` multiple times?

Comment: select * from emails happens one time, then does select * from people where id = :recipient_id N times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a bit Rails 2ish I know and there may be a better Rails 3 way but this does work.

```
@emails = person.sent_emails.find(:all, :include => :recipient)
```

*Edit: See the comment by BaroqueBobcat for a better method in Rails 3*

Comment: you can use `sent_emails.all(:include => :recipient)`

Comment: Used BaroqueBobcat's syntax - that's what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: OK, so in this example I have a Person instance. And I can do "person.sent_emails.all(:include => :recipient)".

And it returns the result I expected. But the person.sent_emails variable is unchanged. How can I load these associations right inside the ActiveRecord instance?